# Converting integer to date and time format?

Tags: sql-server

In sql server, how to convert an integer to date and time, for example :

```
declare @constant int =92011 or 102011
```

How to convert this into date format like 'September-2011' or 'October-2011'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
declare @c int  
set @c = 92011  
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,CAST(RIGHT(@c,4) + '-' + LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) + '-01' AS DATE)) + '-' + RIGHT(@c,4)
```

or 
below case :

```
declare @c int  
set @c = 92011  
select CASE WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 1 THEN 'January' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 2 THEN 'February' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 3 THEN 'March' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 4 THEN 'April' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 5 THEN 'May' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 6 THEN 'June' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 7 THEN 'July' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 8 THEN 'August' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 09 THEN 'September' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 10 THEN 'October' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 11 THEN 'November' 
      WHEN LEFT(@C, LEN(@C)-4) = 12 THEN 'December' 
      ELSE '' END + '-' + RIGHT(@c,4)
```

Comment: In first code you will get error if you will use number like 92011. Sou you should use such code:  'SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,CAST(RIGHT(@c,4) + '-' + LEFT(@c,LEN(@c)-4) + '-01' AS DATE)) + '-' + RIGHT(@c,4)'

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @c int 
set @c = 102011 

;with M(Num, Name) as
(
  select 1,  'January' union all
  select 2,  'February' union all
  select 3,  'March' union all
  select 4,  'April' union all
  select 5,  'May' union all
  select 6,  'June' union all
  select 7,  'Juli' union all
  select 8,  'August' union all
  select 9,  'September' union all
  select 10, 'October' union all
  select 11, 'Novmber' union all
  select 12, 'December'
)
select M.Name+'-'+right(@c, 4)
from M
where M.Num = left(@c, len(@c)-4)
```

Inspired by the use of [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) in answer provided by [Upendra Chaudhari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/889260/upendra-chaudhari).

```
select datename(month, dateadd(month, left(@c, len(@c)-4) - 1, 0))+'-'+right(@c, 4)
```